# Install ActionBarSherlock 4.4 in Android Studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I need help installing/implementing ActionBarSherlock 4.4.0 into Android Studio 0.2.3. I have tried multiple tutorials and looked through answers on here. But none have worked for this beginner.

Has anyone tried to install ABS 4.4.0 into Android Studio yet? Can anyone give me detailed step by step instructions on how to do this? Or point me to an answer or tutorial that will help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I successfully added it as `aar` dependency, no need to download and compile any sources.

1. Open Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager and install latest platform and build tools 18.0.1.
2. Create new project with Android Studio for Android 2.1 (API level 7) and replace `build.gradle` of subproject (not the top one) with the one below.

Complete minimal `build.gradle`, it needs Android Build Tools version 18:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

Comment: Would this be understandable to a newbie?  I consider myself a newbie to Android Studio (having never used it before), and I kinda get what you're saying, but I would have no idea where to put that code thing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I added complete build file, if you generate a simple project with Android Studio and open `build.gradle` you will be able to see the differences.

Comment: @Grzegorz Ok so i don't need to import module?  No need to add dependencies? All i have to add is this to the build.gradle for my project? And how do i make sure it has ABT version 18? In the build.gradle? I am a newbie and if I had not been scouring the internet with other answers and tutorials that mentioned changing the build.gradle i would have no clue haha

Comment: @user2651024 No need to use ABS sources, just add one dependency. I added information about installing build tools.

Comment: @Grzegorz Ok I will give it a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @Grzegorz and rebuilt the project with the basic defaults. No errors in the build. I will work on adding some ABS code and see where that lands me. But in the meantime can anyone answer the issue with ABS Themes? The error i get 'cannot resolve method @style/Sherlock.Theme ?

Comment: @user2651024 Themes seems to be a different issue, make it a new question.

Comment: Where does ActionBarSherlock have to reside in Android Studio?  Does it have to be imported as a library project??

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It does not reside in Android Studio. It is downloaded by Gradle during build time.

Comment: Downloaded by Gradle?  From where?  Where is the Maven repo where ABS is downloaded from??

Comment: I declared usage of only one repository, the Maven Central repository. So the file is here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur sorry for bringing up 1 yr old thread but there's multiple `build.gradle` files. Which one do I put this into?

Comment: @DonRhummy It is the `build.gradle` of subproject. See point 2 in the answer "[...] replace build.gradle of subproject (not the top one) with the one below."

Answer (score 8):

If you are already using Android Studio, you might do it the GUI way.

This also allows you to search the Maven repo, so if you don't know the full name of the 
library no worries.

- Press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S
- Select the module
- Click Dependencies
- Click the green arrow
- Input `sherlock` and press enter to search
- Select `com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar`

This will automatically add it to your build.gradle
[image: Android Studio Project Structure]