# Using actionbarsherlock in Android studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm getting following errors in android studio:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock:compileReleaseAidl'.
> tried to access class com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DependencyBasedCompileTask$DepFileProcessor from class com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DependencyBasedCompileTask
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install ABS 4.4 into Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280400/install-abs-4-4-into-android-studio)

Comment: Use [`ActionBarCompat`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc) if you can. :)