# Using modules dependencies with Android Studio and Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, andengine, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to switch to Android Studio from Eclipse to build and write my apps, but I find it not obvious how to use android modules as dependencies (like ActionBarSherlock or AndEngine).

It is very easy achievable with Eclipse, but I don't know how to do this with Android Studio. I managed to import both AndEngine and my projects to Android Studio, but I cannot get it to compile.

This is how my dir structure looks like:

```
|-Developement
    |--SDK
        |--AndEngine
        |--ActionBarSherlock
        |--Facebook-sdk
        |--.....
    |--Projects
        |--Project1 (depends on AndEngine)
        |--.....
```

With Eclipe, dependencies are configured via workspace or with project.properties, my question is, how to achieve it with AndroidStudio and gradle?

Comment: If you go into project structure in android studio you will see your module dependencies and will be able to add and subtract, change module source directories, etc... as you wish. When you have added a new module you should see it in your project pane

Comment: So you suggest to change source folders etc for my dependencies? Well, I haven't considered it. But will those changes be reflected only in current project and not in global scope (eg. in other project referencing AndEngine?)

Comment: These changes would reflect in your current project scope, not changing the physical location of the dependencies, just your project references to them as needed. you can add a module dependency to any module in your project scope with the green '+' buttons on the project structure pane.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock now has an aar on maven central - you can add it as a dependency in you build.gradle to use it in your project.

Comment: @ MattWhetton yeah, i noticed it :) Thanks :)
@kabuto178 I managed to add dependencies to project, in code, everything looks fine, but the code does to compile :( the errors say that packaged org.andengine.... cannot be resolved. Is there anythindg i need to do with gradle build files to get it work?

Comment: Glad I could help, but I did nothing in gradle, because it was not apart of the project in eclipse. Did you double check the location paths for each of the dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280400/install-abs-4-4-into-android-studio) answer gives a good explanation of how to add ActionBarSherlock as an aar dependency in Android Studio.